# ScrapingHub: ImportError: No module named firebase

Tags: python, firebase, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm trying to put my scraped data on my `firebase` account on cloud , but i'm getting this `ImportError` when i run the spider. I tried making new project and even reinstalling the `firebase` and `shub` on specific version of `Python` but no help.

the spider runs perfectly on my machine , and doesn't show any ImportErrors.
here is the error log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/middlewares.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/app/__main__.egg/Terminator/spiders/IcyTermination.py", line 18, in parse
    from firebase import firebase
ImportError: No module named firebase
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't comment due to reputation. But have you created your requirements.txt?

[Here](https://helpdesk.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200400-dependencies-in-scrapy-cloud-projects) you will find how to deploy your own dependencies to scrapinghub.

Basically you create a requirements.txt file at the root of your project with one dependency per line and add

requirements_file: requirements.txt

to your scrapinghub.yml file

Comment: But isn't that requirement.txt is for the purpose of the error is in the deployment of the project? My project successfully deploys but gives this error while running it.

Comment: requirements.txt will inform scrapinghub which new packages it must install to run your spider. You might deploy successfully and still get import errors.

If you have set the requirements.txt file let me see your scrapinghub.yml